# server.js en Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy arrancando con Nextjs y tengo una duda.
Vi en varios tutoriales que se crea un archivo server.js con una pequena configuracion.
Este archivo es necesario? La data de mi app me llega de dos API ya armadas,a las que llamo desde mi getInitialProps, tengo que implementarlo de todas maneras? si es asi, por que?
Gracias!

Comment: NextJS es un Framework basado en ReactJS para crear aplicaciones que sean renderizadas desde el servidor. Tu archivo `server.js` es el encargado de levantar este servidor en NodeJS. Entonces, sin este archivo no hay servidor y por lo tanto no hay app. ¿Es eso lo que preguntas? Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, si basicamnte era eso, pero si no tengo el server.js (como ahora) siginifica que los html se estan renderizando en el cliente? gracias

Comment: A ver, es que no logro comprender lo que preguntas. Si no tienes un servidor, y NextJS usa un servidor, entonces no estás usando NextJS. Sigo sin entender tu pregunta. Discúlpame si no lo entiendo.

Comment: no hay problema, te explico. Actualmente tengo un proyecto que hice usando nextjs y todo funciona bien, pero no tengo un archivo llamado server.js, por eso no entiendo si nextjs tiene internamente un servidor y esta usando ese o como es que todo sigue funcionando..

Comment: NextJS usa React, el cual a su vez usa Webpack, y el código es  transpilado a JS (internamente por Babel). El servidor levantado por React normalmente no necesita una configuración *persé*. Sin embargo, para servidores personalizados, es necesario crear un archivo llamado `server.js`. Si te refieres a dicho archivo, entonces sí que es opcional. Puedes leer la [documentación](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) al respecto. Ahora creo comprender tu pregunta. Disculpa no haber entendido en un principio. Saludos

Comment: perfecto! ya lo entendi! muchas gracias Mauricio, me despejaste la duda, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario, solamente, es necesario usar el server.js si lo que quieres es usar un ruteo de tu aplicación personalizado, de otra forma el ruteo lo hace next desde tu directorio "/pages"

Saludos!